# Gamma uncertainty in the RHS of a constraint

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, reference-request, robust-optimization

I am new to the concept of robust optimization.I am trying to formulate the robust variation of a Binary Integer Program. Suppose we have a constraint of the form $\sum{x_{i,j}} \geq b_j$ for $ i \in I, j \in J$ with uncertainty in the rhs. We know that each value $b_j$ is going to deviate in a known interval and we known that a specific number of rhs's will deviate (e.g. $\Gamma$ uncertainty).

According to what I researched about the work of Bertsimas and Sim, they consider uncertainty only in the lhs or in the objective and they propose a method to reformulate the uncertainty from the rhs in the lhs by introducing a new variable. Is someone away how to do that or whether is any useful research papers that would help me reformulate the problem and come up with the Robust formulation?

Comment: This question: https://or.stackexchange.com/q/9882/51 seems quite similar.

Comment: It is similar but I have added additional clarification to what I am interested in

Comment: Close votes were issued because this question was asking 2 questions rather than 1. I've removed the second question.