# Budgeted uncertainty on the RHS

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, reference-request

Suppose we consider budgeted uncertainty (Bertsimas and Sim, 2002) for the following scenario. We have a binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$, where $i \in I$ and $j \in J$ (two sets). We then have the following constraint:

$\sum_i x_{i,j} \geq b_j$ for all $j \in J$

The value $b$ comes from a separate set, say $B$, where each element is associated with an element from $J$.

Now we assume, up to $\Gamma$ elements from $B$ are uncertain. How can we derive the robust counterpart or move the uncertainty to left-hand side? Alternatively, can someone point me to relevant literature.

Note: There is similarity to question: [Gamma uncertainty set](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9882/gamma-uncertainty-set)

However, the information provided here is more specific. Alternatively, I seek better explanation or other relevant literature, since the linked paper is not easily accessible.

Comment: If the constraint is for every i,j then why do we have a summation and what is its index?

Comment: @evrenguney I have updated the description for some reason stackexchange does not allow me to put it using \limits

Comment: @PiaMiA, RO webinar this Friday, https://mobile.twitter.com/JannisK13/status/1628036347104489473